# How to open Word document on a shared drive, in read-only mode, every time?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, shared-folders, documents

Is there a way in Office 2010 Pro, to always open the document as read-only when I open it?

At work we store documents on a shared drive. The problem is, quite often someone may need to edit it, but I have it open because I am viewing it. So they need to ask me to close it, just so they can edit it.

Comment: While waiting for better answers, you could always copy the file to your local drive and view it from there. It's a good practice when working with others on a shared drive anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Saving as... Choose under Tools, General Options and check the Read-only recommended checkbox. This will not put the document *always* in read-only but when it is opened, the user is prompted to answer with which state to open the document.

This is the way I prefer to save my documents in a shared folder. Doing so, someone can open the document without locking it for the others.

Comment: Where is the tools menu in 2010?

Comment: Not sure in 2010, but under 2003 and 2007, when choosing File... Save as... It appears in the dialog box

Comment: OK, yeah that is where it is, and this is exactly what we need until we get SharePoint in place.

Comment: This technique is also viable for Excel documents.

Comment: I just checked those steps to select read or edit rights, in Word/Office 2007. In our environment you have the choice of listing people OR selecting ALL in both enironments.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a service like [Google Documents](Https://docs.google.com) or [SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/free-office365-trial.aspx?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=PS_google_Office+365_Introduce_SharePoint_Text#fbid=tEfMC53mjF6).  Both allow for real-time collaboration.

Alternatively, you could change the document properties:

1. Open your document. Click **Review** then choose **Protect**. Click **Restrict Editing**.
2. Select **Editing Restrictions**. Choose **Read Only**.
3. Click **Yes** to protect the document and make it **read-only**.

Comment: Will stepa 1-3  make it read-only just for me or everyone? Also, your're right, I'm looking into share point now. I'm thinking I will need to setup a server for anyone who access documents on that share, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Everyone. I don't think there is a way to open all .docx files as read only. You really, really should consider using [Google Docs](https://Docs.google.com). Its 100% free. It was made for your exact problem.

Comment: I'm going with Sharepoint, these are company docs, which they are paranoid with letting anyone outside the company see. They don't trust Google like that. I can agree with them on this.

Comment: Then just look at this list of companies that trust Google fully...http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/customers/

Comment: I hate people who keep pushing a solution that the people clearly don't trust.  It's just arrogant.

Comment: @wizlog, We use googles stuff, so we trust them, we just don't want company docs out on the net.

Comment: @surfasb, it's a perfectly viable solution, as it would solve our problem with little effort or cost. Where using Sharepoint, its not as easy to learn, plus there are cost and extra resources needed. Plus we have to maintain it. So Google docs is the clear winner.

Comment: Update: Don't forget that the US goverment has access to your documents if it's on their servers.  As with anything that isn't in your possession, you don't know what's happening with it.